# How to update & delete records using Perl Net::MySQL

Tags: mysql, perl

I am spending time trying to get Net:MySQL to work for my database needs but am having trouble finding tutorials on the internet.

From the two examples on the page https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::MySQL

I have been able to read back from my database and insert new records/entries.

**However, I cannot figure out how to update an existing record/entry or delete a record/entry**.

Is there a link you can provide that will help me with the syntax of these two additional functions?

I am unable to get DBI to work on my Mac (actually, it’s DBD that won’t install) so that is why I’m trying Net::MySQL instead.

Comment: Do you know SQL?

Comment: Also, looks like that module doesn't have a way to bind values to parameters in a query? That's... not good. SQL injection makes little Bobby Tables cry. You really should get DBI working and use it instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that would be the answer. I’ll keep trying to get DBD installed.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is *the* universal (or at least global) language for relational database interactions, including MySQL. Examples:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, message) VALUES (1, 'Hello World')
UPDATE foo SET message='Hello, World!' WHERE id=1
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id=1
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-delete-query.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm